# Docker IP-TABLES Error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, iptables

Hey i'm quite new to these docker stuff. I tried to start an docker container with bitbucket, but i get this output.

```
root@rv1175:~# docker run -v bitbucketVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket --name="bitbucket" -d -p 7990:7990 -p 7999:7999 atlassian/bitbucket-server
6da32052deeba204d5d08518c93e887ac9cc27ac10ffca60fa20581ff45f9959
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint bitbucket (55d12e0e4d76ad7b7e8ae59d5275f6ee85c8690d9f803ec65fdc77a935a25110):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -d 172.17.0.2 --dport 7999 -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1)).
root@rv1175:~#
```

> I got the same output every time i tried to activate any docker
>   container. Can someone help me?

P.S. one more question.

> What does 172.1.0.2 mean? I can only say, that this is not my ip.

Answer (score 0):

172.1**7**.0.2 would be the IP assigned to the container within the default Docker bridge network (docker0 virtual interface). These are not reachable from the outside, though you are instructing the Docker engine to "publish" (in Docker terminology) two ports.

To do so, the engine creates port forwarding rules with iptables, which forward (in your case) all incoming traffic to ports tcp/7990 and tcp/7999 on all interfaces of the host to the same ports at 172.17.0.2 on the docker0 interface (where the process in the container is hopefully listening).

It looks like the DOCKER iptables chain where this happens is not present. Maybe you have other tools manipulating iptables that might be erasing what the Docker engine is doing. Try to identify them and restart the Docker engine (it should re-create everything on startup).

You can also instruct the engine not to manipulate iptables by configuring the Docker daemon appropriately. You would then need to set things up yourself if you want to use the network bridge driver (though you could also use the host driver). [Here](https://fralef.me/docker-and-iptables.html) is a good example of doing so.